# give permission of create new revision to specific roles

Tags: users, nodes

I need to give the permission of "create new revision" to a specific role. but nothing related to this issue appeares in permissions page! I've installed [Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) module too.
how can I set it?

Answer (score 0):

**permissions (minimum):**

> **node:**
>
> View published content
>
> View own unpublished content
>
> View content revisions (optional)
>
> [content type]: create new content
>
> **revisioning:**
>
> [content type]: view revisions of own content

**For content types, in its edit UI:**

> Publishing options: Create new revision, New revision in draft,
>   pending moderation (requires "Create new revision")

if you want to do it with Drupal core only, then this will suffice:

> **node:**
>
> View published content
>
> View content revisions (otional)
>
> [content type]: create new content

**For content types, in its edit UI:**

> Publishing options: Create new revision